# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < using bower_components

Tags: javascript

Hi i am getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

My code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contacts</title>
        <base href='/'>
        <link href="src/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Contacts</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't closed `<link />` tag

Comment: ok when i close it showing again

Comment: where are you getting this error? in browser?

Comment: yes console in chrome

Comment: You don't need to close LINK tag [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp). I tested your code in my Crome and it works fine without any errors.